# Mysql trigger not inserting anything

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've created a trigger in mysql, and it's created succesfully but it doesn't work and I have no idea why, I hope somebody here can help me.

The idea is that every time a new "Questionnaire" is inserted, I want the trigger to insert a new record in the table "Status_Quest" with the primary key of every  "User", the primary key of the last iserted "Questionnaire" and a different status according to the user_account_type.

I attached the image of the tables that are involved in the trigger.
Thank you for your help.

This is the code insde the Trigger

```
BEGIN

DECLARE uId int(11); /*Last user ID in the DB */
DECLARE flag int(11) DEFAULT 1; /*Flag for WHILE*/
DECLARE account tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1; /*Account type*/

SET @uId = (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM users);

WHILE @flag <= @uId DO

SET @account = (SELECT user_account_type 
                FROM users 
                WHERE user_id = @flag);

IF
    @account > 1
    THEN
    INSERT INTO statusq (quest_id, user_id, statusquest)
    VALUES (new.quest_id, @flag, 3);
ELSE

    INSERT INTO statusq (quest_id, user_id, statusquest)
    VALUES (new.quest_id, @flag, 1);

END IF;

SET @flag = @flag+1;

END WHILE; 
END
```

[This are the DB tables that are involved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeESz.jpg)

Comment: Possibly it does not enter the while loop. Try adding an insert before and after the loop. Make sure to commit your transaction (outside the trigger)

Comment: Oh yes! that seems to be the problem, I tried the trigger only with the instruction: 
INSERT INTO statusq (quest_id, user_id, statusquest) VALUES (new.quest_id, @flag, 3);
And it tells me that "user_id" cannot be NULL 
but, shouldn't "@flag" have the value of 1 by default?

Comment: Is this a row trigger or a statement trigger? If it's a statement trigger, you don't have access to the `NEW` pseudorecord.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Honestly I didn't have any idea about row and statement triggers, I'm reading about it now. But I modified the value of "@flag" to be set at 1. now it works and it seems to have access to the pseudo record "NEW". Thank you very much!